# Robolectric 4.3.1 fails with message: Android 29 requires Java 9 (have Java 1)

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, robolectric

I'm trying to run my android tests via robolectric, but it get the following error message:

```
at.guger.moneybook.data.repository.AccountsRepositoryTest STANDARD_ERROR
    [Robolectric] WARN: Android SDK 16 requires Java 8 (have Java 1). Tests won't be run on SDK 16 unless explicitly requested.
    [Robolectric] WARN: Android SDK 17 requires Java 8 (have Java 1). Tests won't be run on SDK 17 unless explicitly requested.
    [Robolectric] WARN: Android SDK 18 requires Java 8 (have Java 1). Tests won't be run on SDK 18 unless explicitly requested.
    [Robolectric] WARN: Android SDK 19 requires Java 8 (have Java 1). Tests won't be run on SDK 19 unless explicitly requested.
    [Robolectric] WARN: Android SDK 21 requires Java 8 (have Java 1). Tests won't be run on SDK 21 unless explicitly requested.
    [Robolectric] WARN: Android SDK 22 requires Java 8 (have Java 1). Tests won't be run on SDK 22 unless explicitly requested.
    [Robolectric] WARN: Android SDK 23 requires Java 8 (have Java 1). Tests won't be run on SDK 23 unless explicitly requested.
    [Robolectric] WARN: Android SDK 24 requires Java 8 (have Java 1). Tests won't be run on SDK 24 unless explicitly requested.
    [Robolectric] WARN: Android SDK 25 requires Java 8 (have Java 1). Tests won't be run on SDK 25 unless explicitly requested.
    [Robolectric] WARN: Android SDK 26 requires Java 8 (have Java 1). Tests won't be run on SDK 26 unless explicitly requested.
    [Robolectric] WARN: Android SDK 27 requires Java 8 (have Java 1). Tests won't be run on SDK 27 unless explicitly requested.
    [Robolectric] WARN: Android SDK 28 requires Java 8 (have Java 1). Tests won't be run on SDK 28 unless explicitly requested.
    [Robolectric] WARN: Android SDK 29 requires Java 9 (have Java 1). Tests won't be run on SDK 29 unless explicitly requested.

at.guger.moneybook.data.repository.AccountsRepositoryTest > testUpdateAccount FAILED
    java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Failed to create a Robolectric sandbox: Android SDK 29 requires Java 9 (have Java 1)
...
```

My installed JDK version is 13.

I've added `android.enableUnitTestBinaryResources=true` to gradle.properties and configured `testOptions.unitTests.includeAndroidResources = true` in build.gradle.

My test runner is `AndroidJUnit4::class` as specified in the Robolectric 4.x docs.

Comment: The hint is buried in changelog: https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/releases/tag/robolectric-4.3.1 Change the test Run Configuration in Android Studio to use Java 13 as its JRE.

Comment: I specified my jdk13 for module "app" and "Android JUnit" template, but I'm still getting the error. Perhaps it's because of my `compileOptions`? ```compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }```

Comment: I honestly don't know. One more thing, have you tried with JDK 9? If Android 10 is compioed with Java 9 and Robolectric insists on Java 9 to match Android 10... Maybe they really want Java 9, not 9+.

Comment: Well, in the changelog, they say Java 9+, but I'll try, thanks!

Comment: @the_dani Did you find any solution?

Comment: Unfortunately not, it seems like current Gradle does not support JDK 13 (is a feature of Gradle 6.0), and I think thats why I'm getting an error when building with JDK 13. My current solution is to only test against API 28 (Pie).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Robolectric currently only recognizes JDKs with a version string in a proper format (X.XX.XX):
https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/5303#issuecomment-547029317.

Furthermore, building with JDK 13 is only supported from Gradle 6.0 up.

Answer (score 3):

There is an issue will order versions of Robolectric specifically 4.3.1. Simply upgrade the Robolectric Version to 4.5.1 or later.

```
 implementation "org.robolectric:robolectric:4.5.1"
```

Thanks.